# Override CoreUI variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4, core-ui

So there's this gem https://github.com/pelted/coreui-rails, that uses CoreUI, which is a Bootstrap Admin Template.

Now that template overrode Bootstrap colors and I'd like to override them again to my colors (specifically `-primary`), so that when I use e.g. `btn-primary` class, the button would have my color. I tried this and it doesn't work.

_core-variables.scss file

```
$blue:    #2482dc;

$colors: (
    "blue": $blue
);

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": $blue
)
```

application.scss file

```
@import "coreui-free";
@import "core-variables";
```

**Update**

I tried `@include` functions from either Bootstrap or CoreUI, in both cases they are undefined despite being imported to the CoreUI-rails gem:
https://github.com/pelted/coreui-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/_coreui-free.scss

**Another update**

After some more research and trial&error I found out that I can only override `.btn-primary` using this code:

```
.btn-primary {
    @include button-variant(theme-color("primary"), theme-color("primary"));
}
```

Which is good but it defeats the whole purpose of `theme-colors`. Via this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#components 
bootstrap promises:

"Many of Bootstrap’s components and utilities are built with `@each` loops that iterate over a Sass map. This is especially helpful for generating variants of a component by our `$theme-colors` and creating responsive variants for each breakpoint. As you customize these Sass maps and recompile, you’ll automatically see your changes reflected in these loops."

Is it me doing it wrong or is it a problem with gem? I'm not a Ruby developer, I'm trying to make frontend part work.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hallelujah!

So it turns out that the problem was indeed in this gem https://github.com/pelted/coreui-rails

I found out that `_core-variables` needa to be imported before `coreui-free` file. So I changed my application.scss to this:

```
@import "core-variables";
@import "coreui-free";
```

But it still didn't work so I checked what does this `coreui-free` file do. It looks like this:

```
@import "flag-icon/flag-icon";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons";
@import "bootstrap-variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "coreui/core";
```

Turns out the `bootstrap-variables` essentially were overriding my `core-variables` everytime. I needed to change the order of imports:

```
@import "bootstrap-variables";
@import "_core-variables";
@import "flag-icon/flag-icon";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "coreui/core";
```

Now overridiing a `primary` color is as simple as this:

```
$theme-colors: (
    primary: #2482dc
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running in to a css specificity issue. I would try putting `@import "core-variables"` first, and if that doesn't work, you can always add the `!important` after your variables to make sure that their specificity takes precedence.

Comment: thank you, but I'm afraid it's not the case. I updated the question